# dbcontext in service classes w/ninject

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ninject

Ok, rookie question.  I have a set of service classes the get a dbcontext passed to them in the constructor.  I'm using ninject to handle this:

```
kernel.Bind<DbContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
```

However I'm getting the error: "The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed." When querying to context.

If I just create a new instance of the context in the constructor instead of passing it in everything works.  Is there anything wrong with doing this in a MVC asp.net application?

Comment: it means that somewhere you are trying to get Lazy properties in already loaded entities, but at that moment your DBContext is already disposed. In case of RequestScope you need to dispose DBContext somewhere at the end of Request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being that I was registering one of my services in InSingletonScope.  Stupid mistake and really hard to track down.